# Best way to move LVM on luks to a new hdd?

Tags: lvm, luks

I have a single HDD and there's LVM set up on top of LUKS

```
└─sda5                  8:5    0 883,2G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt (dm-0) 252:0    0 883,2G  0 crypt
    ├─vg1-root (dm-1) 252:1    0    30G  0 lvm   /
    ├─vg1-swap (dm-2) 252:2    0     4G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    ├─vg1-usr (dm-3) 252:3    0    15G  0 lvm   /usr
    └─vg1-home (dm-4) 252:4    0 834,2G  0 lvm   /home
```

Now I bought a bigger HDD and want to move onto it. What should I do after a create a new LUKS partition on a new HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you initialize the new LUKS partition as a LVM PV, add it to your volume group with:

```
vgextend vg1 /path/to/new/LUKS/device
```

Then use the LVM `pvmove` command to migrate your data to it like so:

```
pvmove /path/to/old/LUKS/device /path/to/new/LUKS/device
```

When the data migration is done, be sure to remove the old LUKS partition from the volume group with:

```
vgreduce vg1 /path/to/old/LUKS/device
```

This can all be done with the system online, although it is marginally safer and probably significantly faster to do it from a LiveCD like SystemRescueCD.  Also, if you have a new enough version of LVM, you probably want to use the `--atomic` option for pvmove, that will ensure that you don't end up with some LV's on the new device and some on the old device if the `pvmove` command fails.

Comment: Will luks somehow stand in the way of this procedure?

Comment: As long as the LUKS partitions are open, it should be no different than moving data across regular partitions.  Make sure you use the LUKS devices though, not the low-level partitions themselves, otherwise things won't work.  FWIW, the ability to do this is one of the big reasons I use LVM on almost all of my systems, it makes replacing storage devices ridiculously easy and a lot safer than using dd or a similar tool directly on the partitions.